# Output Selection key on Laptop causes error

Tags: dell-inspiron, function-keys, laptop-display

On my laptop, a Dell Inspiron 1440, the key that I use to select the output selection settings (For example, whether or not to display the laptop screen when using a projector) creates an incredible error. It will cause the screen freeze sporadically and the letter "p" (Lower case) to be constantly input, as if someone was holding the key down. This happens on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04. I'm assuming that it isn't an OS issue. Has anyone heard of this kind of error?

Here's a picture of the key in question, I probably am not clear on which one:

[image]

In Windows, it is supposed to bring up this menu:

[image]

I am no longer using Windows, so any Windows exclusive answers will not help.

If my question does not belong to this forum, could anyone lead me to a correct site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen freezes and it acts like the P key is being held down. It happens across three operating systems. That (mostly) eliminates software. It's either hardware or possibly firmware.

So I would contact Dell to have them try and solve the problem

Comment: Do you think it's a hardware issue?

Comment: I'll go ahead and contact Dell. Thanks for the input!